# How can I get the IntPtr of the bitmap to pass to CreateCaret in c#

Tags: c#, bitmap, caret

I have the following code

```
Bitmap Bmp=new Bitmap( nWidth, nHeight );
using ( Graphics gfx=Graphics.FromImage( Bmp ) ) {
    using ( SolidBrush brush=new SolidBrush( ForeColor ) ) {
        gfx.FillRectangle( brush, 0, 0, nWidth, nHeight );
    }
    Bmp = new Bitmap(nWidth, nHeight, gfx);
    CreateCaret( base.Handle, Bmp, nWidth, nHeight );
}

ShowCaret( base.Handle );
```

The problem I am having is on this line :

```
CreateCaret( base.Handle, Bmp, nWidth, nHeight );
```

... because it is expecting Bmp to be IntPtr

This concept I am trying to do this in a way that does not require loading a bitmap from a file, or resource, but more created on the fly. I understand I can pass `IntPtr.Zero` and it will create a carat however the color is way off if I do it that way.

How can I pass the Bitmap as created to the `CreateCaret` method ?

Comment: You might want to look at the `Bitmap.LockBits` method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I just did, got a 'Lock unavailable in this method or something like that. Fortunately, i was able to find a solution  `CreateCaret( base.Handle, bmp.GetHbitmap(), nWidth, nHeight );` ,  kind of crazy that MS put a method right in there for the conversion yet people are still silly to lock/unlock/etc etc to do the same thing using more memory, resources than needed.  Nice there is a direct way to get a handle to the reference of the object in memory natively.

Comment: I am still having the discoloration issue though, it is showing as a brownish color when I have 'ForeColor' set to GhostWhite, and the background of the richtextbox is Slate, so brown ?  heh.

Comment: Just keep in mind that when using `GetHBitmap`, you are then responsible for deleting the GDI object created: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dz311e4(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method to pass a bitmap is by grabbing the handle to the bitmap. Microsoft has kindly provided the `GetHbitmap()` extension to `Bitmap` types.

This can be done as follows :

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap( 800, 600 );  // create a new bitmap 800x600
IntPtr ptr = bmp.GetHbitmap(); // get the IntPtr handle
```

Using the above example from my question, the Caret creation can be handled as such :

```
CreateCaret( base.Handle,  bmp.GetHbitMap(),  hWidth,  hHeight );
```

Result is the following :

```
// Set the Caret color
Color CaretColor = Color.White;

// Invert the Caret color (ineffective)
Color invertedCaretColor=Color.FromArgb( CaretColor.ToArgb()^0xffffff );

// Get the character size
int nHeight = Convert.ToInt32(gfx.MeasureString("Z", base.Font).Height); // set the height to full character height
int nWidth = Convert.ToInt32(gfx.MeasureString("Z", base.Font).Width); // set the width to full character width

if ( nWidth>0&&nHeight>0 ) {
    // initialize bitmap
    using ( Bitmap bmp=new Bitmap( nWidth, nHeight ) ) {

        // initialize graphics
        using ( Graphics gfx=Graphics.FromImage( bmp ) ) {
            nWidth = Convert.ToInt32(gfx.MeasureString("Z", base.Font).Width * .66); // set the width to 2/3 character width

            // initialize brush for drawing background
            using ( SolidBrush brush=new SolidBrush( invertedCaretColor ) ) {
                gfx.FillRectangle( brush, 1, 1, nWidth, nHeight ); // draw offset by 1 pixel

                // initialize final bitmap for output as Caret
                using ( Bitmap bmp2=new Bitmap( nWidth, nHeight, gfx ) ) {

                    // Draw the Caret;

                    CreateCaret( base.Handle, bmp2.GetHbitmap(), nWidth, nHeight );
                    ShowCaret( base.Handle );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE**
The caret color is ALWAYS calculated based on the background color. This can be modified but the documentation here only gives a rough idea of a concept that it is possible:  [How To Control the Caret Color](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/84054).

The document has this to say on the concept :

> To change the caret color to something other than black or white requires considerably more work, with much less reliable results because the application must solve the following equation:

```
 NOT(caret XOR background) = desired_color on the
                             "blink" of the caret.
```